# My Exciting Travel Adventure

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, word-property, anagram

I have been working hard all year. You know what that means, it's time for a summer vacation! This puzzle will tell you where I am heading!
There are three puzzle sets, with 9 clues each. Each set has a pattern that is revealed through the answers(first letters). You will need to complete the pattern by filling in the 3 missing clues. These three clues will reveal where I am going on vacation.

---

---

> **Homophones pairs**
>
> 1. Bob had to put up the umbrella to protect himself from the sun's bright beams.
> 2. Have you met the guy that delivers our letters and packages?
> 3. While my sedan was in the shop I had to borrow a dealership car, because I don’t have any friends to carpool with.
> 4. I do not know if it will be sunny or if it will be cloudy.
> 5. When you mix dough, don’t use your patella like Alice did.
> 6. I had to walk slowly in the water because I was getting heavily waterlogged.
> 7. I have a strange feeling about a North American lake.
> 8. Bankers verify the validity of every paper transaction a drawer makes.
> 9. ???
> 10. Bob pedaled his bike on the street.

---

---

> What is the **Right Word™**?
> [image: What is the right word™?]

```
Right Words™, Wrong Words™
EIGHT,TWELVE
SANDY,DIRTY
FLOAT,DESCEND
GONE,STAY
HELLO,GOODBYE
RANKING,CATEGORIZE
VOWEL,CONSONANT
FORGE,ESTABLISH
NOTION,CONCEPT
???, ???
```

---

---

> **Anagram Pairs**
>
> 1. Bob couldn’t understand how the _____ was able to _____ out of its    cage.
> 2. There is an Irish ______ that lives on my ______.
> 3. Some Native Americans would call a(n) _____ their modest  _____.
>
> **Find the set of objects referenced in these sentences and the one that is missing.**
>
> 4. **Bob:** Oh Alice, are you Canadian?
>    **Alice:** Why do you ask?
>    **Bob:** I just heard you say “Eh”!
> 5. May Veronica eat my jicama slaw now?
> 6. We still don’t want to leave a stone unturned, nor that rock.
>
> **Here are 4 sets of 4 words. Each set of words fit a certain criteria. Each set will give 2-3 letters that create the *combining word*.**
> Combining Word: Rearranged Marine Animals
>
> 7. Beg, Germ, Me, Slog
> 8. Inn, Medic, Temper, Valid
> 9. Mode, Real, War, Who
> 10. ???, ???, ???, ???

---

---

### **So, where am I spending my summer vacation?**

Hint #1

> The patterns may be a little more difficult than I thought, but think about more *site* related thing. Also, for the "Right" word, the opposite of right is indeed left.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are spending your holiday

> Here on **PSE**!!

---

The first letters of the title say

> **META** - this is important when finding the patterns

**Homophone pairs:**

> 1. **RAISE** (put up) and **RAYS** (sunlight)
> 2. **MALE** (the guy) and **MAIL** (letters and packages)
> 3.  **LOAN** (rent) and **LONE** (friendless)
> 4. **WHETHER** (if/or) and **WEATHER** (sunny/cloudy)
> 5. **KNEAD** (mix dough) and **KNEED** (patella)
> 6. **WADE** (walk in water) and **WEIGHED** (waterlogged)
> 7. **EERIE** (strange) and **ERIE** (Lake Erie)
> 8. **CHECK** (verify) and **CHEQUE** (paper transaction)
> 10. **RODE** (pedalled) and **ROAD** (street)

The pattern:

> The first letters represent the [top tags on the site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags):
>
> Riddle, mathematics, logical-deduction, word, knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, **PATTERN**, rhyme

So word for nine is

> **PATTERN** (P)

---

**Right word**

> Right words form a new word when the first letter is replaced with the letter to the right of it on a qwerty keyboard (well done @user70451 for finding the qwerty rule!)
>
> Eight -> Right
> Sandy -> Dandy
> Float -> Gloat
> Gone -> Hone
> Hello -> Jello
> Ranking -> Tanking
> Vowel -> Bowel
> Forge -> Gorge
> Notion -> Motion

These first letters of the new words

> Are the first letter of the [top users on the site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) (as of now):
>
> Rand al'Thor, Deuosvi, Gareth M, hexonimo, jafe, Tom, Bass, Gamow, M Oehm, **Stiv** (S)

---

**Wordplay**

[user70451 found 1 and 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99978/18250), I found 4 and 5 and [oAlt found 2, 6-9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99961/18250).

Go check out their answers for explanations and consider leaving an upvote! I won't be explaining the solutions here, just including the answer so all the answers are in one place. Hopefully this will make it easier to find the patterns.

Anagram pairs:

> 1: **SNAKE**, **SNEAK**  (S)
> 2: **SETTER**, **STREET**  (S)
> 3: **ADOBE**, **ABODE**   (A)

Missing objects:

> 4: These mention all the vowels (Oh, you, why, I, Eh) except for ‘**E**’
> 5: This is a mnemonic for the planets in order from the sun, and **URANUS** (U) is missing
> 6: **SOUTH** (S)

Combining word:

> 7: **AN**
> 8: **ATE**
> 9: **M**
> 10: **ES** (MANATEES)

The pattern for the third is

> The sites with the [most traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)

So the word is

> Stack overflow, Super user, Ask ubuntu, English Lang, Unix and Linux, Server fault, Arqade, Ask different, Mathematics, **English lang learners** (E)

---

Therefore, the overall answer is

> **P**, **S**, **E** which is here!

Comment: Great word so far! rot13(Gur ubzbcubarf ner pbeerpg, gur cynag zarzbavp vf pbeerpg, ubjrire gur jbeq "ru" vf cebabhaprq nf na "n", fb gung jbhyq yrnir n qvssrerag nafjre.)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie ah ok, I wasn’t sure how that would be said :P

Comment: I have added a hint regarding the pattern :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie found pattern one

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Aha -- and a similar logic yields the third pattern, too

Comment: @user70451 I just got it too :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie solved it all. I'm not sure as to why those particular words are chosen for set 2, but I worked out the pattern before working out the answer.

Comment: Haha, knew you would eventually be the one to finish it :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I also can't see how the answer to the first pattern would fit in the (presumably unrevealed) ninth clue of the first set (i.e., it doesn't have a homophone pair).

Comment: @user70451 I have a feeling we don't need to find an actual word pair, just what the letter the next word pair would start with. Pattern itself isn't a homophone so

Comment: Right -- sorry for the noise, we just need a P.

Comment: @user70451 I think so anyway. There may be an extra layer which determines the words which were used, but I think the OP just selected random words that worked for this.

Comment: Great job, you will earn the check once you decide the "right" rule. Perhaps it has to do with a computers tag(or at least part of it)?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I'll be honest I have no idea for the rule. The others don't seem to have been able to find it either, but maybe someone else will get it.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I don't see the computers tag, but your comment helped me to figure out the rule!

Comment: @user70451 ah thats clever! I'll credit you in my answer :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I believe everything is wrapped up now, unless theres any more patterns we're missing?

Comment: Great job, I am glad you were able to solve all of the underlying clues and patterns. :)

Comment: I don't see anything in the answers about the title. Wink wink.

Comment: @MacGyver88 wow how did we all miss that :P

Answer (score 7):

The first part of the third set also includes:

> 1. Bob couldn’t understand how the **snake** was able to **sneak** out of its cage.
>  3. Some Native Americans would call a(n) **adobe** their modest **abode**.

EDIT 1:
And a stab in the dark (ignoring, for example, the sequences of letters derived from each set of clues):

> Each part has an unknown clue. The third part's final clue could be (as a random example) Fir, Gang, Pip, and Ton -- which is then solved with ES giving the letter **E**. The ninth clue of the first set could use (PAIRS,PEARS), (PAIL,PALE), (PRINTS,PRINCE [a stretch]) etc as solutions, yielding the letter **P**. Then the second set's missing clue presumably solves to the letter **S**.

Whence we find the place where you are spending your vacation:

> PSE -- or right here!

EDIT 2:
It seems we've found the **answer** but not the **solution**. Following mohirl's investigation into Right Words:

> If we replace the first letter of each Right Word with the first consonant alphabetically to the 'right' of that letter we get:
>  EIGHT -> FIGHT
>  SANDY -> TANDY (?)
>  FLOAT -> GLOAT
>  GONE -> HONE
>  HELLO -> JELLO
>  RANKING -> ??
>  VOWEL -> ??
>  FORGE -> GORGE
>  NOTION -> POTION
>  which yields the letter sequence: F,T?,G,H,J,?,?,G,P,?

Or, alternatively unsatisfactory, we get a partial answer by noting:

> One of the letters of the word RIGHT can be used to replace the first letter of each word to create a new word:
>  EIGHT -> RIGHT/TIGHT
>  SANDY -> HANDY/RANDY
>  FLOAT -> GLOAT
>  GONE -> GONE/HONE/TONE (allowing for self replacement)
>  HELLO -> HELLO (see above)
>  RANKING -> RANKING (...)
>  VOWEL -> TOWEL
>  FORGE -> GORGE
>  NOTION -> ??
>  This leads to the letter sequence only consisting of letters in the word RIGHT.

I have not got any traction on the letter sequences, although the third one is:

> an anagram of 'AA MASSEUSE' -- presumably not as good as the AAA version.

EDIT 3:
The answer to the third pattern is

> English (as in English Language Learners, the 10th most popular SE site) -- the top nine are Stack Overflow, Super User, Ask Ubuntu, English Language & Usage, Unix & Linux, Server Fault, Arqade, Ask Different, and Mathematics (SSAEUSAAM)

EDIT 4:
A **Right Word** is a word that

> forms another English word when you replace the first letter with the letter to the right of it on a standard QWERTY keyboard,

which have already been enumerated in [Beastly Gerbil's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99958/70451).

Comment: Correct! Also, welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange :)

Comment: Wow, Correct edit regarding my destination! At that is left to solve is the final logic for part 2 and why I used these patterns!

Comment: I have added a hint regarding the pattern :)

Comment: That pattern#3 is definitely right - great find. Maybe list the rest of the top 10 so we can see the pattern emerge? Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv I've just solved the right words and found the pattern. You may be the answer ;)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Awww, you guys...! *(blushes)*

Comment: @Stiv on the rare occasion you don't solve the puzzle, you're the solution instead :P

Answer (score 6):

For the last set,

> 2. There is an Irish **setter** that lives on my **street**.
>
>  6. (WE ST)ill don’t want to leav(E A ST)one unturned, (NOR TH)at rock. Of course, **SOUTH** is missing.
>
>  7-9. Each set of four words has a similar trick: adding the same suffix to the words in a set will yield words that are still valid English words.
>
>  AN: began, German, mean, slogan
>  ATE: innate, medicate, temperate, validate
>  M: modem, realm, warm, whom
>
>  And I have a feeling that the marine animals we are looking for are **manatees**, with the addition of **ES** to the letters we already have.

About the yet unsolved, I have completely no idea.

> (For the first set I took the letters common between each pair of homophones, but I haven't gotten anywhere with it.)

Comment: I am thoroughly enjoying the idea that #1 in the last set might be BAKER and BREAK - which from context it very obviously is not! Unless Bob is a psychopath... :)

Comment: I have added a hint regarding the pattern :)

Answer (score 4):

Possible starting point for the Right/Wrong words:

> All the Right words can have their first letter changed to form another English word. I don't think any of the Wrong words can.

There are quite a number of possibilities for each though, except for

> HELLO > JELLO

Given that the OPs comment below hints that this is special, perhaps it's that

> It's really a brand name which should be capitalised? Although I can't make the others fit that.

Taking a stab at the others anyway:

> EIGHT > RIGHT (other options, but the list is called Right words)
> SANDY > TANDY (going with brand names) or CANDY / DANDY / HANDY / MANDY / RANDY
> FLOAT > BLOAT/GLOAT
> GONE > loads (BONE, CONE, DONE, FONE(?), HONE, LONE, NONE, TONE)
> HELLO > JELLO (only possibility)
> RANKING > BANKING/JANKING/TANKING. I'm choosing to omit one
> VOWEL > BOWEL/TOWEL
> FORGE > GORGE/JORGE (if we're allowing names, though unlikely)
> NOTION > LOTION/MOTION
> ??? > ???

Giving us the letters:

> R, ? , B/G, ?, J, B/J/T, B/T, G, L/M, ?

Which seems of no help whatsoever

Comment: @Mohirl well, sorry to break it to you, but the first WRONG WORD would skip this logic.
TWELVE>DWELVE.

Comment: I don't think DWELVE is a word?

Comment: Those are great possible answers but which one is "***right***" (hint hint) :)

Comment: @Mohirl Well, I googled it, and "Urban Dictionary" did show it exists. But then, another resource says it isn't an English word at all. Infact, the meaning conveyed by the first resource is pretty close to "Delve", of which Dwelve is a mispelling. Green light I guess, my friend.

Comment: I have added a hint regarding the pattern :)